# Firefox: How to move tabs to the bottom of the window?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I followed [this instruction](http://www.firefoxfacts.com/2008/01/15/move-firefox-tabs-to-the-bottom/);

```
#content > tabbox { -moz-box-direction: reverse; }
```

but the code doesn't work.

Another way is to use Tabmix Plus extension, but the current version of Tabmix is incompatible with Firefox 4.

Comment: tabmix is now updated to v6.x with a development version for 7.x (Aurora)

Comment: @sinni Opera often also runs not so well, for me at least, and doesn't look as nice. I've tried it and just can't get into it.

Comment: Firefox 4 is no longer supported, as far as I am aware, and therefore you really must upgrade for speed, stability, security, performance, feature and standards-compliance improvements.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `Firefox 10.0.7`

At first my `Firefox` tab was like this

[image]

After that I downloaded this `ADD-ONS (Tree Style Tab 0.14.2012081101)` from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/)

[image]

Install that ADD-ONS to Firefox

[image]

After Installing go to **Tools >Add-ons** then this screen will come

[image]

Here in `Tree Style Tab 0.14.201281101` click on `Preferences`

[image]

In **Tab bar position** select **Bottom**

**Done.....**

Now tab will apear at bottom like this

[image]

Comment: Is this even available for Firefox 4? Your are running FF10.(one of the Aurora or Nightly or god knows what builds..damnit Firefox)

Comment: Actually, Firefox 15/16 is now the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: I believe he is on the ESR update channel. This is mainly for businesses/schools, as it does not update as often as the other update channels - it has a far longer period of time before updating. However, you DO get **security** updates in the meantime.

Comment: @Gutsygibbon `Firefox 3.6.24` also support Tree Style ADD-ons. so this will work on `Firefox 4` also.

Comment: Ah thanks for clearly that out max. looks like a good solution. +1

Comment: that option was removed from the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Please explain how specifically how the code doesn't work.
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Move_the_tab_bar_%28Firefox%29

Tab mix plus is now available for FF 4
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu9uTIfogeM

Comment: The mozilla article only moves the tabs below the Location bar. I have also not found in the [Tab Mix Plus manual](http://tmp.garyr.net/help/) any option for it.

Answer (score 0):

*(Currently working for Firefox 116.0.3 as of 2023-08-27)*

This is a very old question, but I recently found out how to do this, so I'm sharing it here.

### 1. Find your Firefox profile directory

- From the `Help` menu, select `More Troubleshooting Information`. The Troubleshooting Information tab will open.
- Under the Application Basics section next to "Profile Folder", click "Show in Finder". A window will open that contains your profile folder.

### 2. Create a `chrome/` directory in the profile directory.

### 3. Create `userChrome.css` custom css rules file in `chrome/` directory

- Copy the contents of [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonhoo/configs/master/gui/.mozilla/firefox/chrome/userChrome.css) (from [@jonhoo](https://github.com/jonhoo)'s configuration files on github) into a file called `userChrome.css` in the newly created `chrome` directory.

### 4. Enable custom css in firefox **`about:config`** settings

- type "about:config" into Firefox's URL bar
- Click "Accept the Risk and Continue"
- In the settings search bar, look for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`, and toggle the boolean to `true`
- Restart Firefox.

Your tabs & URL bar should now be across the bottom of the Firefox window.